How to extract a number value after a forward slash?
I'm trying to extract the second number value after a forward slash. However, some of the records have no forward slashes. For example, let us look at column 'Coverage'. Coverage has two rows, 100 and 250/500
Coverage
100
250/500

In Teradata, when I use substring(Coverage from position ('/' in Coverage) + 1) as Coverage2, the results are
Coverage2
100
500

I would like the results to be null or zero if there is no slash, so ideally
Coverage2
0
500

How can I make this happen? Thanks in advance

Can your data have multiple slashes?  Can it have any characters other than numerals and slashes?

only at most one slash in my data and it is just numerals

In Teradata, utilize a combination of POSITION, SUBSTRING, and CASE functions to extract the second number value after a forward slash.
For example:
SELECT CASE WHEN POSITION('/' IN Coverage) > 0
 THEN SUBSTRING(Coverage FROM POSITION('/' IN Coverage)+1)
 ELSE NULL END


yes, this worked, thank you. also, whoever edited the original question, thank you, it is much clearer, still learning this site

If your data is only like your example (no characters other than / and numerals), this will work. We can use LIKE to determine if your string has a slash, then STRTOK to split the string if it does.  If your actual data doesn't match your samples, this may not work.
create volatile table vt_Foo
(coverage varchar(10))
on commit preserve rows;


insert into vt_foo values ('100');
insert into vt_Foo values ('250/500');



select
case 
    when coverage not like '%/%'  then '0' 
    else strtok(coverage,'/',2)
end
from
vt_foo;

